# Copy files from a list to a folder

Tags: shell, file-copy

I have a text file `abc.txt` and its contents are:

```
   /lag/cnn/org/one.txt
   /lag/cnn/org/two.txt
   /lag/cnn/org/three.txt
```

If I use:

```
$ tar -cvf allfiles.tar -T abc.txt
```

I'm getting the tar of files in the list. Similarly is it possible to copy those files in `abc.txt` to a folder?

I tried this:

```
$ cp --files-from test1.txt ./Folder
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 6):

Note that the standard (POSIX/Unix) command to create a `tar` file is `pax`. `pax` combines the traditional `cpio` and `tar` commands.

To create a tar file, use the write mode:

```
pax -w < abc.txt > allfiles.tar
```

To copy instead, use the copy mode:

```
pax -rw < abc.txt Folder/
```

Note that it recreates the directory structure into `Folder`. If you want to flatten it, you could do:

```
pax -rws '|.*/||' < abc.txt Folder/
```

(see the man page if you want to copy permissions or other attributes as well. `pax` expects one file per line, which means files whose name contains newline characters cannot be copied that way, some `pax` implementations support a `-0` option to allow a `NUL` delimited file list instead).

With `cpio`:

```
cpio -pd < abc.txt Folder/
```

With GNU `tar`:

```
tar -cf - -T abc.txt | (cd Folder && tar xf -)
```

Another option to allow any character in file names is (with GNU `cp`):

```
xargs cp -t Folder < abc.txt
```

(that flattens the directories).

`xargs` expects a blank (space, tab, newline) separated list, when you can escape those separators with backslash, single or double quotes. So you can have a list like:

```
"file with space"
other-file
'file with "quote" and
newline'
```

Comment: +1 for `cpio -pd < abc.txt Folder/` - this worked for me although the file names contained spaces, where other approaches failed.

Comment: @david, what other approaches in my answer failed?

Comment: I only tried `xargs` approaches from your and other answers and they all failed, same as default `cp` variants.

Comment: @david, for `xargs`, as I said in my answer, you need to write the list in the format expected by `xargs`, which is _not_ on path per line.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure where you read that cp has a `--files-from` option, but I certainly don't have that using GNU coreutils 8.22.

As long as your filenames have no newlines in them, you can do this (with bash4+):

```
mapfile -t files < test1.txt
cp -- "${files[@]}" Folder/
```

If you don't have bash4+, then you can manually populate an array and use it (or just call `cp` directly from within `read` for each file, but that will be slower):

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
    files+=( "$file" )
done < test1.txt
cp -- "${files[@]}" Folder/
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by a simple bash script:

```
for i in $(cat path_to_abc.txt)
do 
  cp "$i" path_to_Folder
done
```

A safer way, that can deal with arbitrary file names:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do 
    cp -- "$file" path_to_Folder
done
```

Comment: This will break if any filename contains a character from `$IFS`, which is quite possible.

Comment: @ChrisDown His/her files have simple names! ;) :P

Comment: I don't know how you can tell that from a list of three placeholder filenames.

Comment: @ChrisDown, that also breaks on globbing characters (star, question mark, left square bracket) and filenames starting with `-`. `set -f; IFS=$'\n'; cp -- $(cat path_to_abc.txt) path_to_folder` wouldn't have those issues. (the format of the list file can't allow newlines anyway)

Answer (score 2):

`cp` doesn't have a `--files-from` option (at least, GNU `cp` doesn't) but `rsync` does:

```
rsync --files-from abc.txt -av / Folder/
```

The `/` is used if your `test.txt` file contains files with absolute paths. Otherwise it should be the root of the source.

If your files are zero-terminated rather than newline-terminated you should include the `--from0` option.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to copy the files with similar names you can use this :

Go to the source folder

```
cp $(ls  | grep 'one' | grep 'two') /tmp/
```

So all the files contains the string one and two in their names will be copied to tmp directory

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Note, however, that it is highly [disrecommended to parse the output of `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) as that may choke on special characters (even whitespace), in particular if you use a command-substitution without quoting ...