# Copying files based on input list, special characters in file names

Tags: bash, shell, osx, cp, cat

This is based on the question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106219/copy-files-from-a-list-to-a-folder).

**Problem**:

- I have a  .txt file listing file names I want to copy to the folder *newfolder* in the shell (Mac Terminal).

**Approach**, 
where *filelist.txt* contains file names (separated by \n), that I want to copy:

```
# version 1
for file in $(cat filelist.txt); do cp "$file" newfolder; done
```

**Errors:**

If I have file names in *filelist.txt* that contain dashes, whitespace, etc, the names are split up and I correctly get a `No such file` error.

Here is how I try to address it (adding dbl quotes to the variable):

```
# version 2
for file in "$(cat filelist.txt)"; do cp "$file" newfolder; done
```

But this prints out all the file names (no splitting on whitespace) and does not copy anything.

**Questions:**

- Adding quotes as above addresses the name splitting issue e.g. when I feed it to `echo`; why does it not work for `cp`?
- What is the right way of doing this with `cat` and `cp`?
  A comment in the answer linked above suggests the following:

  `set -f;IFS=$'\n'`

which fixes things but I have not idea what it does.

Any hints are much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of options; this is one:

```
cat filelist.txt | while read file; do
    cp "$file" newfolder
done
```

So, first why does

```
for file in $(cat filelist.txt); do cp "$file" newfolder; done
```

not work? Assume, that your filelist contains

```
a
b c
```

The `$(cat filelist.txt)` produces a list of filenames. The for-loop sees the output of `cat` and interprets it as:

```
for file in a b c ; do
```

which is clearly not the intention.

This is where the remark about the Input Field Separator helps. Normally, the IFS is any white-space and therefore a space in the filename will be interpreted as a separation between filenames. If you set IFS explicitly to a newline, space is no longer seen as a separator.

```
for file in "$(cat filelist.txt)"; do cp "$file" newfolder; done
```

creates a single argument for the for-loop. The result is equivalent of:

```
for file in "a b c" ; do
```

and therefore, the loop gets executed only once, with a filename that does not exist.

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough response; one little thing to make sure I understand correctly re the last item, where you write:
*single argument for the for-loop ... the loop gets executed only once*
--> when I look at this in `echo`, it does not actually `echo line `, `echo line 2` etc but rather echo `line\nline2` etc? that is where i was mistaken that it was "fixed" ...

Comment: @patrick That's pretty much correct, yes.